# Asp.net core application getting error : This localhost page can’t be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

getting this error : This localhost page can’t be found

I am working on ASP.Net core application and were working fine but after adding Scaffolded for Identity I am getting this error ' This localhost page can’t be found' . I noticed scaffolding Identity added the below configuration in program.cs and if I comment this out it then it works fine.

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Below is full program.cs code

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
));
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>(); 

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this 
for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: you can use services in startup.cs  and check again. otherwise give your program.cs code with your question

Comment: I added the program.cs code above

Comment: fixed this issue by adding area attribute [Area("Customer")] on Controller

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue, fixed with adding area attribute on controller:

```
[Area("Changer")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting .net core 6.0 you need to add following package explicitly
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` into your project.

Change your `Program.cs` to include `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` like below

- For RazorPages project

`builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

- For MVC project

`builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

Above changes will allow you change `.cshtml` content even after deployment. That being said, it also mean that you have to deploy plain `.cshtml` files into the server, otherwise 404 will be there.

**Copy all `.cshtml` files for publishing**

Make following changes to your `.csproj` file

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="Pages\**\*.cshtml">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

**Note:** This will copy the into a folder `Pages` just above the `publish` folder while deploying.